# ColdFusion10 CFDocument debug output

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfdocument

Is there a way to capture the complete HTML code from CFDocument before it generates the actual Document/PDF (for debugging)?

[The tag](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdocument.html) itself doesn't seem to support it.

What works partially is storing the separate parts of the HTML via `cfsavecontent` but I can't capture the whole thing at once:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="test123">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        <!-- Style based on paperSize-->
        <cfoutput>
            #request.paperSize.css#
        </cfoutput>
    </style>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfdump var="#test123#" output="#expandPath('./test123.html')#" format="html">
```

So I thought of two ways:

- Raising the log level of the underlying PDF component or some other way to revealing the code from there? (Is it iText?)
- "Escaping" the HTML code so I can read the HTML in the PDF (no idea how to do this in CF)

Any ideas how I could go about this?

Comment: It is itext. It is old. by the looks of this you are trying to check your styling...Are you having styling issues?

Comment: AFAIK you could just replace your `cfdocument` tags with `cfoutput` tags and see the output in your browser. It may not be formatted exactly the same as the PDF output but should be close.

Comment: Yes, I had styling issues. I described the original issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498310/coldfusion10-cfdocument-font-scaling-issue/38498311#38498311) together with the solution. 
Besides that we couldn't come up with an answer to this question.